# How to auto-backup my phone internal storage to my PC (not cloud), using WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, internal-storage, backup, automation

I'm looking for a method to automatically backup my internal storage from my Nexus 6 directly to my PC (not cloud), using WiFi, but I haven't really found a solution for it. I see most solutions use the cloud, but I hate using the cloud. I would like to have it done automatically, on a schedule so I don't ever have to bother remembering. Basically I'm trying to do a PC-like backup (like macrium reflect), but for an Android phone.

Running Nexus 6 with Pure Nexus ROM on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit

Comment: Its possible I use, a tool to achieve this, essentially I do sync job which sync either from  local to remote (i.e android to PC), move from local to remote vice-versa etc. Give me some time to draft the answer..

Comment: With a rooted device and Linux, running SSH as server on the phone and doing periodic backups using `cron` and `tar` over SSH would be the best and most simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in a couple of ways, one of which I use and have tested successfully and the other one equally looks promising and effective. Namely these are:

1. SyncMe Wireless
2. Rsync server and client combo (requires an android sync client and PC (server side) client.

I will try to describe how these methods solve your situation

---

1. Using **[SyncMe Wireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bv.wifisync&hl=en)** application

> SyncMe is an excellent tool to copy, move, sync and backup your mp3,
>   pictures and documents over **Wi-Fi**, (USB tethering, cellular VPN or
>   wired network) to your computer or NAS device.

The biggest advantage of this tool is that  nothing to be installed
 on your computer. Additionally you can sync automatically as long the device is connected to the Wi-Fi by creating automated jobs. The only downside perhaps, is that it currently supports `SMB1` protocol which has been associated with some vulnerabilites and disabled in recent versions of Windows (but won't be much of a big problem since you use Windows 7)

**Prerequisites**

- **Sharing must be enabled on your computer**, the simplest way to do this on Windows is to right click the folder you wish to synchronize (the **backup directory**) select Share With and go with the instructions.

**Instructions**

- The app provides a step-step method of setting a scheduled backup and you simply need to follow the on-screen instructions:
- After download and installation, open the application, connect to your **wi-fi** network and tap on "**Add computer**" on the bottom of the screen, here it scans the IP range of the router until it detects the PC or you can manually enter computer IP:

[image: IMG:]

- After a successful scan, you'll be able to see your PC name listed and input a user account (make sure its **password protected**, also turn on **password protected sharing** in advanced sharing section on your PC.

  Now you need to add a sync/backup job
- Tap on the PC name and select Add sync folder:

[image: IMG:]

- Here you will be presented with the following screen which will enable you to configure the origin and destination folder for the sync/backup job:

[image: IMG:]

- Now select the device (**origin**) folder in this case internal storage `/storage/emulated/0` (or similar) and the computer folder (i.e **destination** folder)
- Next you need to tweak the **Copy to** parameters to suit your backup job:

[image: IMG:]

- When done move to **Schedule option**, here select the automatic job back up parameters that suit you:

[image: IMG:]

*Note: The app has four premium (paid) features in this app: 1) Schedule with router 2) Weekly schedule 3) Include/Exclude directories and files, new extensions and regular expressions 4)*

That should do it. Remember to run the job initially to "test" if you configured correctly.

Disclaimer: Tested and works 100%, I am not related to developer of application, and not related in any other means.

---

**2. Rsync**

Second option is using rsync, which provides a very fast method for bringing remote files into sync.

Firstly take a look at the post prior to gain a better understanding of how this works: [**Backup Android to NAS with Rsync**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49392607/7551330)

**Prequisites**

1. Essentially here you need a Windows rsync client such as [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)or [Acrosync - Rsync GUI for Windows](https://4sysops.com/archives/acrosync-rsync-gui-for-windows/) or any other even native terminal-based rsync.
2. Android rsync client e.g [Syncopoli](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.amoradi.syncopoli/)

   - Configure the virtual backup directories on the target PC, i.e setup the server and the folder using your rsync windows client.
   - If its a bit confusing follow the step by step method [here](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) or [there](https://4sysops.com/archives/acrosync-rsync-gui-for-windows/)
   - Setup your android rsync client by choosing origin and destination folders.

> Configure Syncopoli In the parameters change :
>
> - server address to your NAS IP
> - protocol to SSH
> - private key to the absolute path to the private key on your Android device (i.e `/storage/emulated/0/data/rsynch.key.db`)
>
> In the Action page, create a task :
>
> - Local to remote (for backup on NAS)
> - set a profile name
> - set the source folder to backup (i.e. `/storage/emulated/0`)
> - set a destination

Comment: +1. There is rsync for Windows available too. It can be installed on Windows to run rsync with various options. May require some effort for auto schedule. I'd that is possible you can add

Comment: I haven't actually tried this out yet, but your answer is so elaborate, I have confidence that it will work out. The bounty will go to you. Thanks.

Comment: The solution works, I just wonder what I will have to do if I eventually move onto Windows 10.

Comment: You need `SMB1` enabled manually, but I'm sure at some point the app will be updated to support `SMB2` :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way but it doesn't "automatically" sends/uploads your data to your PC. Using an FTP server in the [Solid Explorer](https://solid-explorer-file-manager.en.uptodown.com/android). Then if your cellphone and PC is connected to the same WIFI then you can access your files on the phone and downloading it in the PC.  [This is how you do it](https://www.trishtech.com/2016/10/using-the-ftp-server-built-inside-solid-explorer-for-android/).

Comment: Please mention the relevant content in your answer, instead of simply linking it. If the link expires in future, the answer would severely lose its usefulness. Thanks.