# Why do I have to download music to Android internal storage then copy to SD card to work?

Tags: samsung, windows, file-management, media-files

Samsung 9+ 
128 GB SanDisk SD Card
Android version 8.0.0 (Samsung Experience version 9.0)
Service provider Verizon

The issue I'm having is with copying music files from my Windows 10 PC directly to the Android's SD card via USB cable. When I do this, the first song in an album is playable, but all the others only play for a second before skipping to the next.

The workaround I found is to copy the files from the PC to Android ***internal storage*** and then to ***move*** them to the SD card storage. Moving the files from internal to SD storage works equally whether I use an Android file manager or Windows explorer.

This is obviously a very cumbersome process when dealing with a thousand files. Ideally, I'd like to download files directly to the SD card. Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How about this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201529/209414?

Comment: This is odd. Have you checked that nothing is wrong with the music player you are using? Maybe try a new one, just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has currently some [bugs](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/mtp-file-transfers-on-win-10-are-broken-in-several/48e3949d-f8d6-4e04-862d-0b173c47b665) in the MTP system (MTP is the system used for transferring data from/to your phone via Windows Explorer). This might be the reason for your problems.

Alternatively you can enable [Debug mode and ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-debugging/info) on your device and then use a GUI tool that uses ADB for file transferring, e.g. this one:

- [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer/releases)