# Backup Android to PC over P2P WiFi connection

Tags: backup, wifi-direct

I want to automatically backup my Android (at least the media files) to my PC over a WiFi connection when both the Android & PC is connected to the same WiFi home network. It should probably be possible to transfer the files directly P2P without needing to store them on some unknown server somewhere. Preferably, I want it to happen fully automatically when it connects to my home WiFi & I have my PC running, so I don't even have to think about doing backups anymore.

I have been searching for the solution, but the closest solution I have found so far is some apps that create a local FTP Server on the phone, where I potentially can manually pull the media files out of the phone from my PC, but I haven't managed to establish a working connection with any of the apps so far.

Is it possible to backup Android to PC over P2P WiFi connection automatically?

Edit_1:

Android 8.0.0 (not rooted)

Windows 7

Comment: There are some [peer2peer solutions](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_1089) like SyncThing where you can keep data in sync across devices. And there's also [FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite) which understands many protocols including e.g. SSH and CIFS so it can talk directly to your PC (you didn't tell us what OS it runs there). With FolderSync you can even define automatic sync whenever a given WiFi is connected, so that might be your solution. Not sure if you'll need the paid version for that.

Comment: I woudl try to minimize the on-device software, e.g. by using [`adb-sync`](https://github.com/google/adb-sync) in reverse mode (device -> PC). As it works via adb it should also work via adb over IP/Wifi. Therefore your PC could regularly try to synchronize the data from your smartphone to the PC. If the smartohone is present in your Wifi it works.

Comment: Progress report: I tried SyncThing, and I managed to make it TECHNICALLY work, but it stops syncing after some seconds & you have to fiddle around for +10 minutes, and when it "works" it can be syncing with the amazing speed of some BYTES per second.... So it's not the kind of "fire & forget" solution I was hoping for. (yes, I also disabled the firewall & the whole security program just to be sure)

Comment: Progress report 2: I tried an app called: PC to Mobile transfer. It connected, BUT it defaulted to the android folder: / that is forbidden. And I found no way to move to an allowed folder.

Comment: Progress report 3: I tried FolderSync, but it seams to sync trough external servers, like DropBox or Google Drive & such. I would prefer a p2p connection if possible. (Also, it's wierd, it "claims" that it can sync files, even before I have set up a sync-destination...)

Comment: @Izzy I tested some of your recommendations as you can see in the "Progress report" comments. I really appreciate your suggestions, I wouldn't have found them myself. (also, I updated the question to include my OS's)

Comment: Though FolderSync *can* use Cloud, you haven't to do that. I use it via SSH/SFTP directly with my Linux machine just fine, same should apply to CIFS for Windows. All depends on how you set it up. So first set up your connection (to your Windows PC via CIFS – I have no Windows, so I cannot give details on that), then configure "folder pairs" to match a directory on your Android device to its counter-part on your PC. In that pair, you can also configure sync conditions (only on WiFi, only with the given SSID etc).

Comment: Just out of interest, you tried this : [How to auto-backup my phone internal storage to my PC (not cloud), using WiFi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/201529/209414) this method uses SMB protocol

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the answer to this and found this question. I went with a simpler method compared to most of the above and it seems to work well. I already use Syncback FREE for my home computers to back up everyone's machines to a central media computer I use as a semi-NAS.

By installing SyncbackSE on the media computer and putting "Syncback Touch" on my phone, I'm able to choose my phone as a source device in the Synckback profile and use it as a backup system just like with my computers. The only differences are that SyncbackSE isn't free (but it's cheap) and all the configuration and management is done on the computer, not the phone (bonus for me, but maybe not for someone using a NAS without an OS and GUI.